# I get an error in sidekiq after a short time of inactivity

Tags: redis, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a job in sidekiq that I run through crontab, now I do it through whenever, I also tried sidekiq-cron and the same error. At startup, everything works, and I get an error after some time of inactivity. Please explain who knows what the reason is.

*code of error in sidekiq*

```
2023-09-06T23:58:13.292Z pid=345687 tid=76xf ERROR: Error fetching job: Waited 7 seconds
2023-09-06T23:58:13.512Z pid=345687 tid=76xf WARN: {"_config":{"labels":"#<Set: {}>","require":".","environment":"development","concurrency":5,"timeout":25,"poll_interval_average":null,"average_scheduled_poll_interval":5,"on_complex_arguments":"raise","error_handlers":["#<Proc:0x00007faa288f6310 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/config.rb:37 (lambda)>"],"death_handlers":[],"lifecycle_events":{"startup":[],"quiet":[],"shutdown":[],"heartbeat":[],"beat":["#<Proc:0x00007faa24b86138 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/metrics/tracking.rb:133>"]},"dead_max_jobs":10000,"dead_timeout_in_seconds":15552000,"reloader":"#<Sidekiq::Rails::Reloader @app=OasisVpn::Application>","backtrace_cleaner":"#<Proc:0x00007faa22da5bf0 /root/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/sidekiq-7.1.2/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:59 (lambda)>","queues":["config","send","default"],"config_file":"./config/sidekiq.yml","tag":"rails_oasis-xray","identity":"ruvds-8q2qu:345687:e3cc59408ef3"}}
2023-09-06T23:58:13.512Z pid=345687 tid=76xf WARN: RedisClient::ReadTimeoutError: Waited 7 seconds
```

*config/initializers/sidekiq.rb*

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 10, network_timeout: 5 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'], size: 10, network_timeout: 5 }
end
```

*sidekiq.yml*

```
:queues:
  - config
  - send
  - default
```

*schedule.rb*

```
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
every 6.hours do
  runner "DeleteConfigsJob.perform_async"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to a weak server and freezes, the time to complete the work exceeded 7 seconds set by default. The problem was solved by increasing the timeout.

```
:timeout: 25
:queues:
  - config
  - send
  - default
```